# Netcat Bad Request

Tags: ubuntu, character-encoding, http, netcat

I'm using Ubuntu and I switched to netcat-traditional version but when I try  to make simple HTTP requests it always failing, any cases, any servers giving 400 Bad request:
(Apache Ubuntu is running on port 80)

```
nc localhost 80
```

I sent plain:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

Simple or complex requests, always giving the same error, I think it can be related with "bash" or "system" encoding but I tested to build a "dummy" HTTP request, like above, and save in a separated file to input directly, but giving the same error (400...):

```
nc localhost 80 < header.txt
```

Comment: Are you sending dos line endings and a blank line after the request?

Comment: What response do you get if you use curl or wget?

Comment: @symcbean No blank line after "Host: ... ", when you refeer to "DOS lines" are you asking about "\r\n" or "\n"? I wrote the header using gEdit, each line with a [return]

Comment: Can't you see what is in the file? (hint: cat -v)

Comment: @symcbean is exactly the above header :/

Comment: @jx12345 with curl it sounds ok, I'm getting 200 code as response, I get the same header that curl used to sent and I tried with netcat but unfortunately I'm getting back a 400 (bad request) :/

Comment: @symcbean I catch it, I tried to use a "pure" print `(printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'; sleep 1) | nc localhost 80` and it works, can I set ubuntu or nano, gedit EOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I catched the problem is all about of EOL. I must use the EOL of MS-DOS (changing "\n" by "\r\n") systems even the server is running in a Linux/Unix.

On save, in case of gedit, it's all solved just by choosing "Windows" on "Line ending" option in "Save As" screen of gedit.